# How to tell cmake to do not assume that a file is config when building deb packages?

Tags: cmake, deb, cpack

When a file is installed in the /etc directory, cmake is automatically assuming that this file is a config one, but my package have scripts installed in /etc (e.g. a script installed in /etc/molly-guard/run.d to control the reboot of the machine), is there a way to flag such files as non config files?

I tried programatically deleting the scripts in the postrm file, but it confuses the debian installer sometimes and it causes a file not found error for the files deleted in the script.

CMake automatically generates a file named "conffiles" in the debian directory (along with control, preinst, etc. created by the user) with all files installed in /etc directory, effectively flagging them as configuration files so the dpkg command won't delete them when the package is uninstalled or install a newer version of them. My question is actually how to edit this file or using a user created conffiles with the correct configuration files.

Here a minimum CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(test VERSION 1.1.0)

set(PACKAGE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})

install(PROGRAMS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test_script.sh DESTINATION /etc/molly-guard/run.d)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

In this example, the script test_script.sh is installed into /etc/molly-guard/run.d and despite being marked as an executable it won't be automatically deleted when the resulting package is removed.

Creating a conffiles does not work because either cmake or the debian package builder (I can't tell which one is doing that) appends a reference to the file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can understand what's happening.

Comment: Hello Tsyvarev, cmake automatically generates a file named "conffiles" in the debian directory (along with control, preinst, etc. created by the user) with all files installed in /etc directory, effectively flagging them as configuration files so the dpkg command won't delete them when the package is uninstalled or install a newer version of them. My question is actually how to edit this file or using a user created conffiles with the correct configuration files.

Comment: Hello Friedrich, I will provide a minimal reproducible example and edit my post, thanks!

Comment: what do you expect to see instead of what you currently see? Is it just the presence of the conffiles file that makes the difference? Or is it something in particular about the contents of that file? (see also the instructions on providing a [mre])

Comment: Tsyvarev - "That explanations are better suited for the question post itself" ok, done.

Comment: Hello user, I was expecting that the conffiles would not have test_script.sh included on it but it gets included and even if I create a conffiles myself without test_script.sh it gets appended after building the debian package. That's really annoying.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: Interesting question. I can't test your example right now, but it seems that you're supposed to use `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA` to add files to conffiles. I can't find any documentation talking about cpack automatically adding them there. I suppose you could use the mentioned variable to remove the files you don't want in there, but that doesn't feel like the way it's supposed to be at all.

Comment: related docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html#variable:CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA